# DataGrid Blazorise export to Excel or CSV?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, blazor, blazorise

Is there any possibility to directly export all the data from the DataGrid (from Blazor) to Excel, CSV or any other data structure, without manually coding this?

Many frameworks support this, but I couldn't find anything like that for Blazorize DataGrid.